# What is the real Outlook 2013 mailbox size?

Tags: exchange, microsoft-outlook-2013

Outlook 2013, (cached mode). Exchange Server 2007. Clients are Windows 8.1

In Outlook 2013, click FILE and view account information, under MAILBOX CLEANUP, it says something like "13MB free out of 2.49GB".

[image]

I have set the Exchange Server to NO LIMITS. But, I still see all the Outlook clients say there is a 2.49GB limit (The server has been rebooted several times now so it is not some delay in processing).

Where/what is this limit??? From what what I can tell, it is not the OST limit.

Comment: "it says something like "13MB free out of 2.49GB"." I can't seem to find what you're speaking of. Where _exactly_ are you seeing this info in Outlook?

Comment: In Outlook 2013, if you click FILE, then the information in the RIGHT pane has mailbox info. Note: you only see this if you are using Exchange CACHED mode.

Comment: FYI: this is the 32-bit version of Outlook (Click-2-run) on Windows 8.1 64-bit

Comment: I have Outlook 2013 running in Cached mode, and I can't find where you're talking about. Can you provide exact steps of how you're getting there (the last two sets you gave are different, and neither show me what you're talking about), or perhaps a screenshot?

Comment: OK, I'll try to put a URL to a screenshot in here

Comment: ooops.... <https://www.dropbox.com/s/y0aard1uvmub03g/ScreenShot027.jpg?dl=0>

Comment: Weird, mine does not show me that info. If you run `Get-Mailbox <User ID> | Select *quota` from an Exchange Management Shell prompt on the Exchange server (using the user ID of the user in question), are any Quotas set?

Comment: I have tried that and it indicates "NO LIMITS" on all entries. All of my clients show this 2.49GB number and I don't know where it comes from.

Comment: Where did you set this "no limit" setting. Please discribe that. How big is you exchange database and how many users do you have? Is it SBS Exchange Server or a normal Exchange Server? As well this might be better to ask on server fault.

Comment: I used THE Get-Mailbox <User ID> | Select *quota command. Shows NO LIMITS. This is regular Exchange 2007. About 50 users. The database is about 69GB at this point.

Comment: This is an example of one user and Exchange settings   https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ptd4axylebydgo/ScreenShot056.jpg?dl=0